# Density Maps for Materials moving along Conveyors in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I'd like to show congestion areas on a conveyor network by using the density map included into the Material Handling Library, but so far I haven't find a way to do so, as material agents movement cannot be tracked by the density map, but it only accepts transporters or pedestrians (both in free space movement mode).

So I thought I could create a "parallel" agent (for instance, a pedestrian) that could get attached to my material and move along with it. Then I could set the pedestrian visible property to "no" so that it does not show in the animation, or make it really small as an alternative approach.

The problem when doing the pickup/dropoff logic is that the pedestrian disappears from the scene when it gets picked up (although it's internally batched with the material) so the density map shows nothing.
Same thing happens if I try to seize/release a transporter, as they do not travel along the conveyor with the material agent.

Any idea on how to get this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to drag pedestrians, they actively move via `PedMoveTo` blocks. This is a creative idea but it will not work.

You will have to code your own heatmap using dynamically colored rectangles that you animate on top of conveyors. Doable, but might be more work than is really required for your purpose ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, Benjamin, really appreciated!

Comment: @ecarran Glad the answer was helpful. Please upvote this answer as “useful” (up-arrow next to the answer) to help other users find it in the future as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote for more info on how SOF works :)